# How can i open the main navigation drawer programmatically from inside the attached fragment?

Tags: android, fragment, navigation-drawer

I have created a navigation drawer activity and I want to remove the toolbar of the activity and use the custom toolbar in different fragments, now I can't find any way to open and close the navigation drawer from inside the fragment.
Like in main navigation activity the drawer can be open and closed on the click of the hamburger menu, but how can I open the drawer from the attached fragment to it.

Comment: show the code that you've tried

Comment: you need the activity's context in your fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom listener:

```
class Frag extends Fragment{

   NavigationOpenListener listener;

   public interface NavigationOpenListener{
      public void OnDrawerOpen();
   }

   public void openDrawer(){  // Call this method when you want to open drawer from your Fragment
      if(listener!=null)
      listener.OnDrawerOpen();
   }

   public void setOnDrawerOpenListener(NavigationOpenListener onDrawerOpenListener){
      this.listener=onDrawerOpenListener;
   }

}
```

And listen on your `Activity`:

```
  Frag frag1=new Frag();
  frag1.setOnDrawerOpenListener(new Frag.NavigationOpenListener() {
     @Override
     public void OnDrawerOpen() {
        yourDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
     }
  });
```

Comment: It worked for me, thanks. I almost forgot about the interfaces. :)

Comment: You are most welcome, thanks for accepting as answer.

Comment: Worked for me too... Thanks

Comment: Thank you too.. Liking my answer is enough ))

Comment: There is another way too.. You can write a method in Parent Activity to open drawer.. And in Fragment you can call it like this ((YourActivity)getActivity()).openDrawer();

Answer (score 0):

First of all create static instance of navigation drawer activity and then call public method of change fragment from your fragment like following

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    static MainActivity instance;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        instance=this;
    }

    public static MainActivity getInstance()
    {
        return instance;
    }

    public void changeFragment(Fragment targetFragment)
    {
            getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fl_main_container, targetFragment, "fragment")
            .setTransitionStyle(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
            .commit();
    }
}
```

From Fragment call method like following

```
MainActivity mainActivity=MainActivity.getInstance();
mainActivity.changeFragment(new FragmentHome());
```